# Android, combining bottom navigation with tabs (Activities vs. Fragments)

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

Hell community,

I am new to Android and I could not find a good answer to that problem:

I want to use a bottom-navigation and some of the elements should also use tabs.

Now my question is what is the most common (best) way of implementing that?

I am confused in if I should use activities or Fragments for this navigation.

Is it an okay way just using fragments for both, the bottom-navigation and the tabs or is the best way using activities for the bottom-navigation and only fragments for the tabs?

Best regards

Comment: Using both bottom navigation and tabs on the same screen may confuse users, as explained here: https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#usage.
Before implementing such navigation pattern, ask yourself if you could improve your navigation workflow to avoid mixing tabs and bottom navigation. if you figure out that's really what you need, I'd be glad to help you !

Comment: @ThibaultSeisel

I read that as well before.

I need a way to navigate through some top-level destinations as well as some tabs to navigate between some content within the same hierarchy level.

I am not sure if the combination of Navigation drawer and tabs would be better but currently, I am planning 5 destinations for my bottom-navigation but it could end up being just 4. The material guideline suggests using bottom navigation with 2-5 elements and only navigation drawer with 5+ elements.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to use `Fragment`s for both. If you use an `Activity` for each screen reachable from the bottom navigation, you will have to put a `BottomNavigationView` in each and duplicate a lot of code, as well as tweaking transitions between those activities.

Activities should be considered entry-points of your application: when clicking on the app icon in the launcher, the main activity defined in the Manifest is started.
For anything else (portions of the UI, parts of a navigation flow...) you may use `Fragment`s.

Here is a sample Activity and Fragments organization to solve your case:

```
MainActivity
     |--- TopLevelFragment1
     |--- TopLevelFragment2
     |           |--- TabFragment1
     |           |--- TabFragment2
     |           |--- TabFragment3
     |
     |--- TopLevelFragment3
     |--- TopLevelFragment4
```

As you can see in the above schema, an Activity can host child fragments, and fragments can also have nested fragments (also called "child fragments").
`TopLevelFragmentN` are fragments that are displayed when selecting an item in the `BottomNavigationView`. `TabFragmentN` are fragments that are displayed when selecting  a Tab from `TopLevelFragment2`.

Let's dive into the implementation. I have not tested the following pieces of code, those are just provided for guidance.
Here is sample code for the activity:

#### main_activity.xml

```
<CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout">
  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_host"><!-- TopLevelFragments will be displayed here --></FrameLayout>
  <BottomNavigationView android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"/>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        // Retrieve a reference to the BottomNavigationView and listen for click events.
        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            // Depending on the clicked item, change the displayed TopLevelFragment.
            switch(item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.top_level_1:
                    showTopLevelFragment(new TopLevelFragment1());
                    return true;
                case R.id.top_level_2:
                    // Do the same with other TopLevelFragments
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        // Show the first TopLevelFragment by default.
        showTopLevelFragment(new TopLevelFragment1());
    }

    private void showTopLevelFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        // Use the fragment manager to dynamically change the fragment displayed in the FrameLayout.
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_host, fragment)
            .commit();
    }
}
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView#setonnavigationitemselectedlistener) to understand how to define items in the `BottomNavigationView`.

Now, let's focus on the `TopLevelFragment2` that contains tabs. It is a common pattern to use `TabLayout` with a `ViewPager`, so that you can move from one tab to another by swiping left or right.

#### top_level_fragment_2.xml

```
<ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/constraint_layout">    
    <AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/appbar_layout">
        <Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
        <TabLayout android:id="@+id/tab_layout"/>
    </AppBarLayout>
    <ViewPager android:id="@+id/tab_pager"/>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

#### TopLevelFragment2.java

```
public class TopLevelFragment2 extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_level_fragment_2, container, false);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        MyTabPagerAdapter tabPager = new MyTabPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        ViewPager viewPager = getView().findViewById(R.id.tab_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabPager);

        // Display a tab for each Fragment displayed in ViewPager.
        TabLayout tabLayout = getView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    static class MyTabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        MyTabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3; // One for each tab, 3 in our example.
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch(position) {
                case 0:
                    return new TabFragment1();
                case 1:
                    // Return a new instance of the fragment associated with the tab at position 1
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After those steps, all you have to do is to write the code for the other fragments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

Tried to implement it like this but when I try to use the AppBarLayout within the constraint layout I do get the error message:

This inspection highlights unallowed XML tags in Android resource files and AndroidManifest.xml.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're right, `AppBarLayout` should only be used as a direct child of a `CoordinatorLayout`. I suggest replacing it by a `LinearLayout` as it will have the same behavior as `AppBarLayout` (minus the scrolling effects), so that you can test your implementation of bottomnav + tabs.

Comment: This is really helpful.. I was already implementing this design pattern. In my case, I also need to have a DrawerLayout. Can you please tell me how can I include DrawerLayout as well? A starter code or sample link would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I can see the tabs in my fragment loaded. However, these fragments are being displayed as totally blank. Even though I have added TextViews in both of these fragments, but those are not being displayed. Any clue?